# NAgios: add/import a list of host to ping, automatically?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, ping

I am searching for a way to automatically add a few hundreds of hosts to ping in Nagios. 
I guess there could be procedure or a file to fill with something like an `/etc/hosts` file to have Nagios to simply ping these hosts.
 another common service would be to probe for ssh availability.

Comment: https://www.nagios.org/ncpa/help/2.0/api.html

Comment: How automatic are you expecting?  Something like puppet/ansible can build out nagios configuration really quickly.

Comment: more automatic than adding 300 machines by hand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use template like this:

```
nagios/etc/servers/host1.cfg
nagios/etc/servers/host2.cfg
....
nagios/etc/servers/host300.cfg
```

Template:

```
define host{
        name                    host-1
        use                     generic-server
        host_name               host-1
        alias                   host-1
                                #change 
        address                 127.0.0.1
 }
```

for generate .cfg file for all servers from file,like hosts - you may create shell script.

And use crontab for run it and reload nagios service.